# Validation rule for phone number

Tags: validation

how to write validation rules for phone number  in below    format

+()-

Example :     +(91)-1234567890

When end user entering value for phone number it should only allow  mentioned special characters    + () -    and numeric numbers.

exiting validation rule

IF( ISBLANK(End_User_Contact_Phone__c) , false, NOT(REGEX(End_User_Contact_Phone__c, "\D*?(\d\D*?){10}")))

Comment: I modified like this. is it right ?                                                             IF( ISBLANK(End_User_Contact_Phone__c) , false, NOT(REGEX(End_User_Contact_Phone__c,"^(\\+)[\\(\\)-][0-9]")))

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick given the requirements:

```
NOT(REGEX(Phone, "[0-9+\\-\\(\\)]*"))
```

But it will allow for some funky phone numbers that are definitely *not* valid, e.g. "+123-+()()()"

Comment: If this is the answer that worked you should mark it as accepted (tick next to it). This isn't me angling for points, but it helps identify the solution to those searching later on, and it also helps our site stats!

Comment: NOT(REGEX(Phone_Number__c, "[0-9+\\-\\(\\)]*"))

using  validation rules.It's auto formating in US format but when record save in application.It's throwing message.
Just I want to need to add space in validation rule. How can I add.

Comment: As per @LaceySnr's answer, just following the regex, escape the whitespace character `\s`. So your new regex will look like : `NOT(REGEX(Phone, "[0-9+\\-\\(\\)\\s]*"))`